# What is the quickest/easiest solution to getting data from a DataGridView into a local SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, datagridview

I have a DataGridView (datagridview2) with several columns of data.  I have a local SQL database table (ResultsDB.sdf) that I'd like to store the data from the datagridview in.
Is there a quick way to do this?  Or do I need to read each row in the DataGridView and write it out to the SQL table using SQL statements?

Thanks for any helpful advice!

Comment: "What is the quickest/easiest solution to getting data from a DataGridView into a local SQL table?" - asking the readers of StackOverflow to write the code for you? ;-)

Comment: No no!  Not at all.  A general push in the right direction will help.  Should I use a 'foreach' to loop through each row in the datagridview?  Or, can I bind the SQL table to the datagridview and get the data into it that way?  Just looking for advice, not code (although code examples are appreciated).

Comment: I know. I was just joking - your question is just fine!

Comment: Doh!  Sorry about that.  I totally missed the smiley icon on the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are tons of binding samples for sql server to datagridview control over internet. just try one of them...
to start, read following article which has a good simple sample for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx

Comment: That's a great link.  Thank you very much!  I'll check out those examples and see what I can come up with.  I greatly appreciate it, Afshin!